# Delete rows with a certain condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have a data frame and I want to delete rows that in the column "Phrase", pattern "___" exists.

| Index | PHRASE | Label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | proposed by the president of the | 1 |
| 1 | Living ___ | 1 |
| 2 | "Murder, ___ Wrote" | 0 |

```
But Imagin that the data fram has 2,000,000 enteries
```

```
import re

df_clean = pd.DataFrame()
z = 0
y = 0
for i in df_original["PHRASE"]:
  x = re.search("___", i)
  if x:
    y = y + 1
  else:
    df_clean.append([i])
    z = z + 1

this is what I came up with so far, I know it's not right, Does anyone know the answer? (by the way append takes a lot of time)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df[~df['phrase'].str.contains('___')]
```

Where the `~` symbol negates the operation.

Comment: sorry I'm new to stack overflow,I just did.